# Geometric intuition about Jacobian of unit normal vector to surface and orthogonal projections

Tags: vector-analysis, surfaces, vector-fields, jacobian

**Background:**

Let $M=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by an implicit equation for a smooth $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ with non-zero gradient. We can define the unit normal vector
$$n(x)=\frac{\nabla f(x)}{\|\nabla f(x)\|},$$
everywhere in a neighborhood of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Then we can define the orthogonal projection onto the tangent plane of $M$ at a point $x$ by
$$P(x)=I-n(x)n(x)^T,$$
where matrix-multiplication is being used. So $P^2=P$.

**My question:**

Let $J_n(x)$ be the Jacobian of the normal vector $n$ at $x$ and let $a(x):=(J_n(x))n(x)$. Is it always true that
$$P(x)a(x)=a(x)?$$

**Some thoughts:**

I have verified this for some examples, like the sphere (in which case $a(x)=\vec{0}$), and the ellipsoid (in which case $a(x)\neq \vec{0}$). I am not sure how to prove it in general, but it seems there is some good geometric intuition that I am missing here that if someone could comment on, it would be very helpful. I have also noted that, since $P=I-nn^T$, the claim is equivalent to saying
$$(n(x)n(x)^T) a(x) =0,$$
i.e.
$$a(x)\in \ker n(x)n(x)^T,$$
for all $x\in M$. Writing out the matrices and trying to solve the equation in general does not seem feasible, so I think I am missing out on some linear algebra or differential geometry facts. Perhaps it is something like saying $Jn\cdot n$ is in the tangent space of $M$ at $x$ so that $P$ leaves it as it is. Like I said, my geometric intuition is a bit lacking in high-dimensions, so it would be great if someone could clarify this not just analytically but with some geometric flare.

Comment: What is $J$ at all ? are you still there ?

Comment: @Physor $Jn(x)$ is the Jacobian matrix of the normal vector $n(x)$ at $x$, i.e. the $i$-th row is $\nabla n^i(x)^T$ where $n^i$ is the $i$-th coordinate of $n(x)$.

Comment: @Physor if it is preferred, notationally, to just write $J$ for the Jacobian of $n$, I can edit it, of course.

Comment: You say *projection onto $M$ at $x$*; of course, you mean projection onto the *tangent plane of $M$ at $x$*. What you're writing doesn't make sense, actually. Since $n$ is defined only on $M$, you can't compute its directional derivative in the direction normal to $M$. However, you're meaning to use the formula $\nabla f/\|\nabla f\|$ to define a map on an entire open subset of $\Bbb R^3$? I want to clarify this point before proceeding further.

Comment: Basically, all that's going on here, once you make the right definition of your mapping, is the observation that the derivative of $n$ always lands back in the tangent plane of the surface. This still holds even when you have a family of surfaces, as you do with the level surfaces of $f$ here.

Comment: @TedShifrin you are correct on both points. $n$ is defined everywhere in a neighborhood of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Sorry I was being sloppy. I am still getting used to these subtleties and precise terminology.

Comment: @TedShifrin The only thing I am missing, though I believe it is obvious for anyone more familiar with the subject, is why the derivative of $n$ always lands back in the tangent plane of the surface. How can this be proven rigorously?

Comment: Sure. Just differentiate $n\cdot n = 1$  to get $dn_p(v)\cdot n(p)=0$ for any vector $v$. Use a curve $g(t)$ with $g(0)=p$ and $g’(0)=v$ and the chain rule, if that’s easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, it should be as follows. The mentioned Jacobian is the derivative of the map (vector field)
\begin{align}
n:&\mathbb R^3 \to T\mathbb R^3 \cong \mathbb R^3 & x &\mapsto (\nabla f(x))/\|\nabla f(x)\|
\end{align}
The integral curves (aka filed lines) of the gradient and those of $n$ are the same lines, (both are tangent to these curves), but $n(x)$ are by definition *unit* tangent, so its derivative along an integral curve $\gamma: \mathbb R \supset I \to \mathbb R^3$ is orthogonal to it, i.e. (the crucial point is)
$$
n(\gamma(t)) \perp \frac{d}{dt}n(\gamma(t)) \equiv n'(\gamma(t)) = J_n(\gamma(t))(\gamma'(t)).
$$
where the chain rule was used. The jacobian is the linear-map-valued field
\begin{align}
J_n:& \mathbb R^3 \to L(\mathbb R^3;\mathbb R^3) & \left[J_n(x)\right]_{ij} = \partial_j n_i(x)  
\end{align}

Now acting the Jacobian at a point $J_n(x)$ on a small vector $v \in \mathbb R^3$ gives us the small change in $n(x)$, i.e $(J_n(x))(v) \approx n(x+v) - n(x)$. If $v = \gamma'(t)dt$, i.e. is a small tangent vector to an integral curve $\gamma$ of $n(x)$, we get that corresponding change $$
n(\gamma'(t)dt +x) - n(x)\approx (J_n(x))(\gamma'(t))dt
$$
which is orthogonal to $n(x)$. So your defined map $a: x \mapsto (J_n(x))(n(x))$ has its images orthogonal to the integral curve $\gamma$, and so orthogonal to $n(x)$, and so its projection is
$$
P(a(x)) = a(x).
$$
This $a$ is the acceleration of the integral curves of $n$, and it is normal to these curves.

Comment: Interesting, +1. It will take me some time to digest this, however, due my geometric intuition being weak in high dimensions. Do you have any references or textbook suggestions that might deal with this? If you could add those to the answer that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I'm busy this week, I'll checke that later and improve my answer. I wrote it when I was very drowsy (sleepy)

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand\PD[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
$

**Edit:**

I decided I should maybe explain why $a(x) = (n(x)\cdot\nabla)n(x)$.

Rather than as a matrix, for fixed $x$ we may view the Jacobian of $f : \R^m \to \R^n$ at $x$ as a linear function $Jf(x) : \R^m \to \R^n$ which may be expressed as
$$
  [Jf(x)](y) = (y\cdot\nabla)f(x),
$$
where $\nabla$ acts on $f$ and the resulting derivative is evaluated at $x$; perhaps more clearly
$$
    [Jf(x)](y) = \bigl[(y\cdot\nabla_z)f(z)\bigr]_{z=x}.
$$
To verify this, consider $y = e_i$ of the standard basis:
$$
  [Jf(x)](e_i) = (e_i\cdot\nabla)f(x) = \PD f{x_i}(x),
$$
for $x = \sum_{i=1}^mx_ie_i$, which is exactly the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ column of the Jacobian matrix.

---

We may write $a(x) = (n(x)\cdot\nabla)n(x)$. Note that $\nabla$ is only acting on the $n(x)$ on the right. The projection $P(x)a(x) = a(x)$ if and only if $a(x)$ is orthogonal to $n(x)$; so we look at $a(x)\cdot n(x)$, abbreviating $\PD{}r := n(x)\cdot\nabla$ and suppressing $x$ dependence:
$$
  a\cdot n
  = \PD nr\cdot n
  = \frac12\PD{}r(n\cdot n)
  = \frac12\PD{}r1
  = 0,
$$
so $a(x)$ and $n(x)$ are orthogonal.

Comment: I am a little confused by the notation here. Conventionally, the gradient $\nabla f$ of a function is defined for real-valued functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\nabla f$ being in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But here $n: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector-valued function So I am not sure what $a=n \cdot \nabla n$ means in the first line. So sorry, but can you clarify this notation?

Comment: @NapD.Lover $n\cdot\nabla$ is the derivative in the direction $n$, just like $\frac\partial{\partial x_1}f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = e_1\cdot\nabla f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is the derivative in the $e_1$ direction. If $$n = n_1e_1 + n_2e_2 + n_3e_3$$ in the standard basis, then $$n\cdot\nabla n = n_1\frac{\partial n}{\partial x_1} + n_2\frac{\partial n}{\partial x_2} + n_3\frac{\partial n}{\partial x_3}.$$ Perhaps $a(x) = (n\cdot\nabla)n$ would be clearer; I'm used to $\cdot$ taking precedence.

Comment: @NapD.Lover I added an explanation for why $a(x) = (n(x)\cdot\nabla)n(x)$. I hope that helps to clarify further.